# Nonnegative solution of a linear system with a upper triangular coefficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove (or find a counter-example) that any arbitrary linear system of the form $Ax=b$ has a non-negative solution $x$ where
$A$ is square matrix of size $2^n\times 2^n$ such that
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
^{\otimes n} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \dots \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{n},
$$
and $b$ is a $2^n \times 1$ matrix of real values such that $0 \leq b_{i+1}\leq b_i$ for $1\leq i \leq 2^n - 1$. The symbol $\otimes$  stands for the Kronecker product.

What I know: $A$ is a upper triangular matrix where the diagonal are all ones. Hence, $\det(A)=1$ and eigenvalues are all 1.

What I tried: As $A$ is in upper triangular form and $b$ is in a decreasing format ($b_{i+1}\leq b_{i})$, I tried to proceed as if it was the final steps of the Gauss elimination. In this way, it seems that at each variable substitution, the $b$ will change but will remain non-negative, but I cannot write this formally.